# What is the name for rings that are a union of ideals and finitely many subrings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Some rings have the property that they are a union of (proper, nontrivial) ideals.

- $\mathbb{Z}$ is a union of $2\mathbb{Z},3\mathbb{Z}, 5\mathbb{Z}, \dots$
- $R[x]$ is a union of $xR,x^2R, \dots$

But some rings are not, for instance:

- $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$
- $\mathbb{Q}$

(Those are the ones I can think of right now -- I would love to hear some others!)

Is there a name for rings with this property?

**EDIT:** As G. Sassatelli points out, no ring has this property because no ideal can contain $1$. In particular, the correct decompositions are:

- $\mathbb{Z}$ is a union of $\{1\}$ and $2\mathbb{Z}, 3\mathbb{Z}, 5\mathbb{Z},\dots$
- $R[x]$ is a union of $R$ and $xR,x^2R, \dots$

So I suppose my question is: what is the name for rings that are a union of ideals and finitely many subrings? (I guess $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ has this property under the new definition, but I don't believe $\mathbb{Q}$ does.)

Comment: No ring $R$ has such property, because the union of all the proper ideals of $R$ cannot contain $1$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: Ah, I see where I went wrong with $\mathbb{Z}$; I need $1$ in there. But what about $R[x]$? (Why is your statement true?)

Comment: Because, if $A$ is a (commutiative unital) ring, any ideal of $A$ which contains $1$ is the whole $A$. In fact $$\bigcup\left\{I\subseteq A\,:\, I\text{ ideal}\wedge I\neq A\right\}=A\setminus A^*$$ $A^*$ being the group of elements which  have a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: $R$ is a subring of $R[x]$, not an ideal (in fact, $xR\nsubseteq R$).

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: Gotcha. Thanks. So my question has to do with rings that are "mostly" unions of ideals, I suppose. I'll amend it.

Comment: No quotient $A$ of $\Bbb Z$ (so neither $\Bbb Z$ not $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$) has the property you say, because, since no proper ideal can contain $1$, then $1$ must be contained in a proper subring. But, since $A$ is a quotient of $\Bbb Z$, the only subring of $A$ which contains $1$ is $A$ itself.

Answer (score 0):

(Not really an answer, but too long for a comment)

As @G.Sassatelli points out, in every ring $A$, the union of all proper ideals  is exactly $A\setminus A^*$. It's easy to see : no element of $A^*$ can be in a proper ideal, and any non-invertible elements is in the proper ideal it generates.

In particular, what you say about $\mathbb{Z}$ and $R[x]$ is false : $\mathbb{Z}$ is the union of its prime ideals and $\{\pm 1\}$ (you forgot $-1$) ; and $R[x]$ is not the union of $R$ and the ideal $(x)$ : for instance $1+x$ is in neither of these sets.

So maybe your question can become : "when is $A^*$ contained in the union of finitely many proper subrings ?".

Comment: In your first paragraph, you want commutative rings: there are noncommutative rings $A$ for which $AxA=A$ for some non unit $x$, for example, take $A$ to be the Weyl algebra $A=k[z,\partial_z]$ in one variable. Then $z \partial_z-\partial_z z = 1$ gives $A=AzA=A\partial_z A$, but none of $z,\partial_z$ is invertible in $A$.